# Limit job folder permissions

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to limit the folder permissions that a job will have access to across the server?

So that a job (let's call it `testing`) can't access anything outside its own job folder (in this case it would be `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testing`).

Currently, it is possible to for example delete system files from a job inside my Jenkins setup.

Anyhow to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently, it is possible to for example delete system files from a job inside my Jenkins setup.

The Jenkins server itself should have its own account (see "[Jenkins installation on Debian/Ubuntu](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#debian-ubuntu)")

And the slave, as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/9547214), should also have its dedicated acount: that way, any job running on that slave would not be able to delete files its account does not own.